# I want to Extract only the Mail in a given string using RegExp

Tags: c#, regex

the Given string :

```
/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=GMAIL.ONMICROSOFT.COM-52001-KARNIK@GMAIL.COM213

/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=GMAIL.ONMICROSOFT.COM-52001-AHMED@GMAIL.COM213
```

OUTPUT :

```
 KARNIK@GMAIL.COM

AHMED@GMAIL.COM
```

I m using this pattern but it is not working

```
^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$
```

Comment: please provide 2-3 more sample string input.

Comment: Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript).  The topic of writing a regex to cover an email address has already been well covered on this site.

Comment: `@` is present only in `AHMED@GMAIL.COM` ? means no any occurence of `@` except email?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this . I try this according to the above sample. I you add some other sample string so it would be great to write strong regex.

**Regex:**

```
[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+
```

**Output on regex101:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to retrieve email from your input string is,

1) Split your string by hyphen(`-`).

2) Take the 3 splitted string with index `[2]`.

3) And remove digits from splitted string.

```
string input = "/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=GMAIL.ONMICROSOFT.COM-52001-AHMED@GMAIL.COM213";

string output = new string(input.Split('-')[2].Where(x => !char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** ***The above code only works for OP's provided input.***

Comment: Nice Thank you :)